# Vs 2017 Installer Fails on "Mobile development with .Net"

Tags: android-sdk-tools

```
======================================
: Windows 10 x64, Vs 2017 Pro 15.7.2 :
======================================
```

I'm getting the error (below) when installing the "Mobile development with .Net" components with Vs 2017 Pro while running "As Administrator".

I've tried:

1. Removing and re-adding the components
2. Repairing Vs 2017
3. Installing the HAXM download by itself (which installed fine)
4. Uninstalling and reinstalling Vs 2017
5. Reporting the problem to microsoft

Anyone know how to fix?

```
===============
: Install Log :
===============

Something went wrong with the install.

You can troubleshoot the package failures by:

    1. Search for solutions using the search URL below for each package failure
    2. Modify your selections for the affected workloads or components and then retry the installation
    3. Remove the product from your machine and then install again

If the issue has already been reported on the Developer Community, you can find solutions or workarounds there. If the issue has not been reported, we encourage you to create a new issue so that other developers will be able to find solutions or workarounds. You can create a new issue from within the Visual Studio Installer in the upper-right hand corner using the "Provide feedback" button.

================================================================================

Package 'AndroidTools_Xamarin,version=26.1.1.3' failed to install.
    Search URL
        https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=AndroidTools_Xamarin;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=5
    Details
        Command executed: "c:\windows\syswow64\\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -Noninteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -InputFormat None -Command "& """C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\AndroidTools_Xamarin,version=26.1.1.3\AndroidSDKPrivateInstall.ps1""" -Package tools -FileName sdk-tools-windows-4333796.zip -Version 26.1.1 -AndroidHome """C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk""" -RequestedAVDs """""" -Operation Install; exit $LastExitCode"
        Return code: 5
        Return code details: Access is denied.
    Log
        C:\Users\bminder\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20180530193011_361_AndroidTools_Xamarin.log
    Impacted workloads
        Mobile development with .NET (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat,version=15.7.27625.0)
    Impacted components
        Android SDK setup (API level 27) (Component.Android.SDK27,version=15.7.27625.0)
        Google Android Emulator (API Level 27) (Component.Google.Android.Emulator.API27,version=15.7.27625.0)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Package 'AndroidHaxm_Xamarin,version=6.2.0.4' failed to install.
    Search URL
        https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=AndroidHaxm_Xamarin;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=5
    Details
        Command executed: "c:\windows\syswow64\\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -Noninteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -InputFormat None -Command "& """C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\AndroidHaxm_Xamarin,version=6.2.0.4\AndroidSDKPrivateInstall.ps1""" -Package extra-intel-Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager -FileName haxm-windows_r6_2_0.zip -Version 6.2.0 -AndroidHome """C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk""" -RequestedAVDs """""" -Operation Install; exit $LastExitCode"
        Return code: 5
        Return code details: Access is denied.
    Log
        C:\Users\bminder\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20180530193011_362_AndroidHaxm_Xamarin.log
    Impacted workloads
        Mobile development with .NET (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat,version=15.7.27625.0)
    Impacted components
        Google Android Emulator (API Level 27) (Component.Google.Android.Emulator.API27,version=15.7.27625.0)
        Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM) (global install) (Component.HAXM,version=15.6.27413.0)
```

Comment: Read the log and fix it from there. `Return code details: Access is denied.` So `powershell.exe` a fital application is either missing or requires admin privileges. Not recommended but you can test with installing as "raised privileges". Not sure how that is specifically called in Windows but it can be done with a right mouse click. If that is recommended, I don't think so but worth a try. Perhaps try to create shortcuts to the maybe missing applications.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was our corporate Cylance blocking the script. I had to put in a request to allow it - only lost 2 days doing so.